# while giving background to imageview how to solve bit map size exceeds exception in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

hi am doing one app here i am using more images, here in arraylist i am having images i convert those arraylist to  array then i add that string array to imageview but when the activity starts that time i am getting bitmap size exceeds exception.only some time i am facing this problm,but some times its working well.some times only i am facing this prblm... i tried many ways but no result.i mention below my code any one having idea pls suggest me.

```
 LetterGameActivity .class:

 public class LetterGameActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

           birdimg1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.birdimg);
        option11 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.opt1);
        option12 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.opt2);
        option13 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.opt3);

                        option11.setText(stringArraynew[0]);
            option12.setText(stringArraynew1[0]);
            option13.setText(stringArraynew2[0]);


             BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), stringArraynew3[0], options);
            int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
            int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
            String imageType = options.outMimeType;

            birdimg1.setImageBitmap(
                    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), stringArraynew3[0], 100, 100));
}

   public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
    if (width > height) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
    } else {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
    }
}
return inSampleSize;
  }
 protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
System.gc();
   }
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
       System.gc();
    }

    }
```

Comment: is there any use of code which is starting from "option13.setText(stringArraynew2[0]);" and end at "birdimg1.setImageBitmap" in oncreate function ?? because those variable didn't use.

Comment: yes here i need provide onclick funtion to those textviews,and imageview

Comment: check out this pastebin http://pastebin.com/d3GeeBkQ , i put comment on the code for which i am aksing.